# boto elastic beanstalk CreateApplicationVersion 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto

I've finished a python script that deploying automatically to Elastic beanstalk.

It works fine with testing environments.

But when I just changed user key, Boto says '403 Forbidden' with correct policy.

https://policysim.aws.amazon.com say's that user allowed CreateApplicationVersion.

However boto don't allow CreateApplicationVersion action.

```
boto==2.28
python==2.7.5
```

Anyone got this problem before?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upload_to_aws.py", line 135, in <module> 
description=None, s3_bucket=AWS_ELASTIC_BEANSTALK_S3_BUCKET_NAME, s3_key=zip_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/beanstalk/layer1.py", line 156, in create_application_version
return self._get_response('CreateApplicationVersion', params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/beanstalk/layer1.py", line 71, in _get_response
raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 403 Forbidden
{"Error":{"Code":"AccessDenied","Message":"User: arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:user/<username> is not authorized to perform: elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion on resource: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-northeast-1:<account-id>:applicationversion/<application-name>/<application-version>","Type":"Sender"},"RequestId":"<request-id>"}
```

IAM policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1000000000000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
      ]
    },
{
      "Sid": "Stmt1000000000001",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-northeast-1:<account-id>:environment/<application name>/<environment-name>"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think this is a boto issue.  It just makes the API call with the credentials you provide.  If the service says `403` then the credentials you are using are not authorized for that operation.

In the case of the `CreateApplicationVersion` operation, you also have to pass in an S3 bucket where the version data is located.  Does the account you are using have access to that bucket?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.Before the CreateApplicationVersion operation, I upload the zip file to S3 bucket. It uploded well. But when I tried the CreateApplicationVersion operation, it says 403. some other operation likes describe_applications(), describe_environments(application_name=AWS_ELASTIC_BEANSTALK_APP_NAME) works properly.